# how to design tablet ui with high resolution but less density screens?

Tags: android, tablet, hdpi

I want the emulator to make use of the files present in the `xhdpi` folder and at the same time it should have low density. My emulator is set to a resolution of `1280 X 800` similar to `motorola xoom` tablet. Now if i keep a density of `149 ppi`, android does not access the `xhdpi` folder. Please help. TIA.

Comment: I have more than 20 reputation, still i don't have the chat priviledge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not misunderstand `Screen size`, `Screen density` and `Resolution`. Read [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms) first.

Comment: So, technically it's not possible to have a tablet UI with screen density 160 ppi. According to the article `320 ppi` density is suitable for tablets

Comment: Generally there is no connection between density and screen size. You can have 10' screen with small resolution, this will be xlarge screen with mdpi density.